# Array object not displaying in id="main" in a for loop using onchange function

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, onchange

I am using document.write because it displays what I wanted it to display. It works, but it will remove the other contents of the page in the ID that I am trying to display it on. Is there a way I can display this for loop inside the id="main"? When I try using document.getElementById("main").innerHTML, it will only display that last data in the array, which is the city of Normal. That is about it. Can someone help me?

```
var cities = [
  { city: "Bloomington, IL",
    latitude: "40.4842° N, 88.9937° W",
    population: "77,962",
    elevation: "797 feet (243 m) above sea level",
  },
   { city: "Normal, IL",
     latitude: "40.5142° N, 88.9906° W",
     population: "54,742",
     elevation: "869 feet (265 m) above sea level",
   }
];


function displayCityInfo() {
  var x = document.getElementById("cityInfo").value;
  if(x==1){
    document.write("<h2>Results</h2>");
    for(i=0; i<cities.length; i++){
        document.write("Welcome to the city of " + cities[i].city
        + ", latitude is " + cities[i].latitude + "<p>");
    }
  }
  else if(x==2){
      document.write("<h2>Results</h2>");
      for(i=0; i<cities.length; i++){
          document.write("Welcome to the city of " + cities[i].city
          + ", population is " + cities[i].population + "<p>");
      }
  }
  else if(x==3){
      document.write("<h2>Results</h2>");
      for(i=0; i<cities.length; i++){
          document.write("Welcome to the city of " + cities[i].city
          + ", elevation is " + cities[i].elevation + "<p>");
      }

  }
}

  <body>
    <h1>City Information</h1>
      <label>Select an option:</label>
      <select id="cityInfo" onchange="displayCityInfo()">
        <option selected disabled>Select an option</option>
        <option value="1" enabled>Latitude/Longitude</option>
        <option value="2" enabled>Population</option>
        <option value="3" enabled>Elevation</option>
      </select>
    <main id ="main">
    </main>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.innerHTML` works fine. What you want to do is instead of going `.innerHTML = "content"` you would use `+=`. This will add whatever you want onto the inner HTML of the element.
So for example,

```js
// This will *set* the content to be an H1 with 'Hey'
document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = "<h1>hey</h1>";

// This will *add* a paragraph tag to 'main'
document.getElementById("main").innerHTML += "<p>How is it going?</p>"
```

So the 'main' will now be

```html
<div id="main>
    <h1>hey</h1>
    <p>How is it going?</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Quick answer**

Whenever you use document write as you just did it will overwrite that entire page. That is the behaviour happening when document.write is in the onchange callback.

To fix this, you need to create your string first then append it to the dom. There are multiple ways to do that.

```js
    function displayCityInfo() {
        var x = document.getElementById("cityInfo").value;
        var m = document.getElementById("main")

        if(x==1){
          var cityInfoStr = "";

          for(i=0; i<cities.length; i++){
              cityInfoStr += "Welcome to the city of " + cities[i].city
              + ", latitude is " + cities[i].latitude + "<p>";
          }
          m.innerHTML = "<h1>Result</h1>" + cityInfoStr
        }
    }
```

Please note the following:

1- you should create the text maybe in a p tag (look into creating child nodes using JS)

2- innerHTML function is not a safe function (check security issues with it for cross-site scripting)

**explanation**

according to the specs:

> This method has very idiosyncratic behavior. In some cases, this method can 
>   affect the state of the HTML parser while the parser is running, resulting in a 
>   DOM that does not correspond to the source of the document (e.g. if
>   the string written is the string "" or '<'!.. . In other
>   cases, the call can clear the current page first, as if
>   document.open() had been called. In yet more cases, the method is
>   simply ignored, or throws an exception. Users agents are explicitly
>   allowed to avoid executing script elements inserted via this method.
>   And to make matters even worse, the exact behavior of this method can
>   in some cases be dependent on network latency, which can lead to
>   failures that are very hard to debug. For all these reasons, use of
>   this method is strongly discouraged.

From: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dynamic-markup-insertion.html#dom-document-write

---

Comment: @crmcarpio please upvote answers so they help others as well.